# "npm start" command suddenly stopped working with "create-react-app" project folders with both old and newly created projects

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal

I've been using `create-react-app` to make some projects in react and also for practicing, and usually the way to run the project is to use the command `npm start` from the root directory of that project in the terminal. This has since stopped working for both my old projects which I haven't touched or completely new ones, and **followed the exact instructions given by the error already to no effect**.

An image of the error, the very top of the terminal is immediately after the `npm start` command:

[image: npm start error with create-react-app projects]

I have been googling this over the past two days and I simply can't figure it out. I'm hoping someone with better knowledge would know the root of why `npm start` has stopped working. Please keep in mind that I already tried the suggestions provided by the error in the terminal.

What's really mind boggling is I haven't changed pcs or done any editing in the old projects such as the one in the picture above, re-installed a bunch of stuff I thought might have been causing issues like `npm` or `babel` but they simply don't launch anymore.

Also almost forgot the error log, which has been even more confusing to figure out or google:

[image: Error log for failing npm start.]

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your dependencies. Please run

```
npm i
```

inside project directory.

As your console shows, you can try

- remove your node_modules directory
- delete file package-lock
- I suggest clean npm cache (npm cache clean -f)

and reinstall node_modules using

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to cause this problem.Some suggestions here:

1.uninstall babel-loader and create-react-app globally

```
npm uninstall -g babel-loader
npm install -g create-react-app
```

2.remove the error package

```
rm -rf ~/node_modules/babel-loader
```

3.stop all the command then clean up the cache of npm